# What is the $q$-analog of $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi z)}$?

Tags: gamma-function, theta-functions, q-analogs

I would expect the [$q$-Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function) to have the property which would be the $q$-analog of the Euler reflection formula from my question title.

More concretely: $\Gamma(z)$ has simple poles at nonpositive integers, $\Gamma(1-z)$ at positive integers, and together they fold nicely to give (up to scalar multiple) $\csc(\pi z)$, the simplest periodic function with simple poles at all integers.

An analog of this I would expect would have in place of $\csc$ some form of theta function with poles at all integer powers of $q$, the $q$-analog of $1-z$ would be $q/z$, the $q$-analog of $\Gamma$ would have poles only at nonpositive powers of $q$, and then the same function of $q/z$ would have poles at positive powers of $q$, so their product would give that theta function.

Is there such an identity? I could not quite find it.

Comment: [This article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1012459209474) discusses $q$-analogues of the Euler reflection formula and the Euler gamma integral.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot, I would never find it myself! Would you make it an answer?

Comment: This is a very different use of the letter "q", but the "q-aspect" version of the identity $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$ in analytic number theory is the identity $\tau(\chi) \tau(\overline{\chi}) = q \chi(-1)$ for Gauss sums $\tau(\chi) = \sum_{n \in {\bf Z}/q{\bf Z}} \chi(n) e(n/q)$ of Dirichlet characters of conductor $q$.  (Gauss sums show up in the functional equation for Dirichlet L-functions in much the same way that Gamma factors show up for the Riemann zeta function.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde After some confusion, I've checked the paper and it seems that they get the same which made me stuck: denoting $\Gamma_q(x)\Gamma_q(1-x)=f(q^x)$, one obtains$$f(qz)=-zf(z),$$whereas I would expect to obtain a function with $f(qz)=f(z)$.

Comment: Also, the following article discusses $q$-analogues of the Euler reflection formula.  http://icms.kaist.ac.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/BKMS-51-4-1155-1161.pdf

Comment: @MartinBokner Astounding paper indeed, thank you very much for the reference!

Comment: @MartinBokner Hi, I can't access that file - any chance you have another working link?

Comment: @TheWheelisBeforeDescartes [The q-deformed Gamma function and q-deformed polygamma function](http://pdf.medrang.co.kr/kms01/BKMS/51/BKMS-51-4-1155-1161.pdf) by Won Sang Chung, Taekyun Kim, and Toufik Mansour (Bull. Korean Math. Soc. **51** (2014), no. 4, 1155-1161)